# Column varchar and issue about index or fulltext?

Tags: php, mysql

Well I have a column varchar for password on my table and at some scripts i make queries like:

`length(column_varchar) < 10`

My question is if i put a index on this column, it will help? or in this case should use fulltext? or don't need a index?

Another question i need to use index in all columns that will be used in 'where'?

Comment: It is recommended to index all columns used in "where". I do have a question though, when would you ever need to search the "password" column? Surly, your password column only contains password hashes, right?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, yes my stored password is a md5.

Comment: md5 is not a secure hash. You can read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php - The thing is that a password column should only contain one way hash, including salt. If you can search to see the length of a password or to find a match through an SQL-query, your hash is probably implemented the wrong way.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, understand it, but should i use index in this column? it would help queries that make something like: length(column_varchar) < 10?

Comment: A full text index is used to perform natural search (as in search for "best of series" and find "series best"). It won't help in detecting invalid hashes. (Why is finding invalid hashes such a common operation that you even need an index?)

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you aware of `composer` project for PHP? If yes, how come you are solving a problem that's been solved already? There are people who wrote authentication systems which are tested and probably better than yours. Why don't you use code that's made available by other developers? Also, you're using `md5` to hash passwords - that's not exactly secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes are used to index content (field value), not the length of the field, therefore no index can help in the above query. (N. B. you could have a sparate field that has the content length and index that separate field.) Also, the password should be stored in a hashed format, so all password lengths should be the same, or at least should not be a criteria for selection.

No, you should not index all columns that will be used in a where criteria. Selecting the optimal index structure is a complicated and very broad topic. Always consider the following points when trying to determine what fields (or combination of fields) to index:

1. Indexes speed up selects, but slow down data modification, since you have to update the index as well, not just the column's value.
2. MySQL can use only 1 index per table in a query.
3. MySQL uses the selectivity of the indexes to determine which one to use. A field that can have 2 values only (yes / no, true / false) is not selective enough, so do not trouble yourself with indexing it.
4. Always use the `explain` command to check which indexes your queries use.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two questions here, in general you should split questions up.

Anyway, the first "Will it help indexing a column where you doing a test for length."

No, it won't.  The only way you could improve the performance here would be to have an additional column that holds the length of the value in column_varchar and index that.

You wrote in comments that you are holding hashes, so the lengths will all be the same, so I have to guess that some passwords are null and so you don't hash them, or that you are migrating from not hashed to hashed.

The second question: should you index all fields in a where clause.  This is not an automatic yes, which is why there are books written about query optimisation.

It depends on how much benefit you will get from the index, and that depends on the nature of the data.

The main trade off is between insert speed and query speed.  Indexes slow inserts and speed up queries.

The next thing to consider is selectivity.  If the value you are indexing has only three potential values, for example, the database will need frequent updating of the index to get real value from it.

In this specific case, you have evenly distributed data ( because it is hashed), you have great selectivity ( MD5 has few collisions) and you are expecting to query more often with a single term, so you should definitely be indexing this column.